# MissingMethodException on Google Contact embedded dll

Tags: c#, reflection, embedded-resource, google-contacts-api, missingmethodexception

I want make a c# Library (library scope is communication with Google contact api) with dependency **embedded** in library.

So, in my class constructor i put this code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, evento) =>
            {
                var assemblyName = evento.Name.Split(',')[0].Trim();
                if (assemblyName.ToLower().Equals("google.gdata.contacts"))
                    return Assembly.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetEmbeddedResource("Contacts.Assembly.Google.GData.Contacts.dll"));
                else if (assemblyName.ToLower().Equals("google.gdata.client"))
                    return Assembly.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetEmbeddedResource("Contacts.Assembly.Google.GData.Client.dll"));
                else if (assemblyName.ToLower().Equals("google.gdata.extensions"))
                    return Assembly.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetEmbeddedResource("Contacts.Assembly.Google.GData.Extensions.dll"));
                else if (assemblyName.ToLower().Equals("newtonsoft.json"))
                    return Assembly.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetEmbeddedResource("Contacts.Assembly.Newtonsoft.Json.dll"));

                return null;
            };
```

In this way, when **AppDomain** try to resolve Google contact library or its dependency i return my embedded assembly.
This WORK!!!

My problem is when i call this code:

```
RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("ApplicationName");
ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
```

This code same work for RequestSettings (this class is in google.data.client.dll) but when try to create ContactRequest instance (this class is in google.data.contacts.dll) it raise "**MissingMethodException**".

Why code return this error?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Check your *google.data.contacts.dll*: probably it depends on another dll you are not including (e.g. log4net).

Check also your inner exception, it should include details on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem!!! Unlike, AssemblyResolve event is raise each time that caller use an not referenced assembly. But, in my code I loaded each time the same assembly but for AppDomain they are different assembly. In example:

MyDLL raise AssemblyResolve to load: **google.gdata.client** and **google.gdata.contact**
then application instance ContactRequest (google.gdata.contact). But this dll raise AssemblyResolve to load: **google.gdata.client**

For AppDomain google.gdata.client (loaded in MyDLL) **is different** to google.gdata.client (loaded for google.gdata.contact).

To resolve problem, build a dictionary with all dll to load, so when domain request to resolve an Assembly the code return ever same Assembly